# $L^{1}$ norm of a horizontally shifted measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose we are in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), m)$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

Also, suppose $g: \mathbb{R} \to [-\infty, \infty]$ is in $L^{1}(dm)$.

I want to understand why $\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} |g(y)| dy = \int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} |g(y-x)| dy$.  That is, for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $||g(x)||_{1} = ||g(y - x)||_{1}$ holds.

Is this an obvious fact?  I realize that $g(y - x)$ is measurable for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you know that Lebesgue measure is translation invariant, i.e. $m(A+x)=m(A)$ for all Borel sets $A$ and real $x$? Once you know that, it is not too hard to show your claim.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks, saz's answer relied on this fact and now I see what you both mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$, define a mapping

$$\tau_x: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, y \mapsto y-x.$$

Then $\tau_x$ is continuous (hence measurable) and $\tau_x^{-1} = \tau_{-x}$. By definition,

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(y-x)| \, m(dy) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g \circ \tau_x(y)| \, m(dy).$$

We can rewrite the right-hand side using image measures:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g \circ \tau_x(y)| \, m(dy) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(z)| (\tau_x m)(dz) \tag{1}$$

where

$$(\tau_x m)(B) := m(\tau_x^{-1}(B)) = m(\tau_{-x}(B)) = m(B+x)$$

denotes the image measure of $\tau_x$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $m$. Since the Lebesgue measure is translation invariant, i.e.

$$m(B+x) = m(B)$$

for any Borel set $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, we conclude $\tau_x m = m$. Hence, by $(1)$,

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(y-x)| \, m(dy) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} |g(z)| \, m(dz)$$

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is when you rewrite the RHS using image measures.  Here is what I *think* is going on: The right hand size is the integral of $|g(z)|$ with respect to the measure $\tau_{x}(m) \,dz$.  I.e., the right hand side is $\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}} |g(z)| \,d(\tau_{x}m\,dz)$.  Does that sound right?

Comment: @user46944 Yes, that's correct. Unfortunately, there are several notations for the image measure: $$\tau_x(m) = (\tau_x m) = m_{\tau_x} = m(\tau_x).$$ They all mean the same thing - namely, the distribution of $\tau_x$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $m$.

Comment: Ok, I will keep thinking about your answer, but it makes sense.  The whole point is that Lebesgue measure is translation invariant (probably because the Lebesgue measure of open intervals is translation invariant).  Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: @user46944 Yes, that's the point. First, you prove it for intervals - then by the uniqueness of measures, the translational invariance carries over to all Borel sets: $$\int 1_B(x+z) \, dz = \int 1_B(z) \, dz.$$ And then, using the standard procedure (i.e. approximating measurable functions by simple functions), we see that the claim holds for any measurable (integrable) function.